# Is it possible to identify the USB communication mode programatically?

Tags: java, android, usb

Is there a way to *programatically* identify the currently USB working mode?

I mean, some function that would return either if the device is at `Host`, `Device` or `Accessory` mode.

Comment: Do you mean the USB working mode of the device?

Comment: @Aify, yes. I have a situation where Android can change the USB working mode and I need to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer, but once you have a UsbManager you might be able to figure it out. Usually this UsbManager is created using a Context I believe, but it looks like you are switching modes so you hopefully can get a UsbManager instance, `m` in this case:

`UsbManager m = createManagerSomehow`

For accessory mode, this only has one callback. If this returns one then you know it is Accessory.

`m.getAccessoryList()`

So I'm thinking somehting like this might work:

```
if(m.getAccessoryList().size() > 0)
    accessoryMode = true;
```

And for Host, if you have a UsbDevice `device`, or String `deviceName` you could use the same UsbManager `m` function to see if it contains that device.

```
if(m.getDeviceList().containsValue(device))
    hostMode = true;
```

or

```
if(m.getDeviceList().containsKey(deviceName))
    hostMode = true;
```

and I don't know about what `Device` is, but if none of the above are true then you know it is just a Device. You don't really need this boolean variable below, because you have the other two. It's just here to help with my explanation via state logic.

```
if(!hostMode && !accessoryMode)
    deviceMode = true
```

Hope this helps. Check out UsbManager for more documentation and just search the page for Host and Accessory.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html

NOTE: I am a little confused when  you say you switch the modes in your comment. It conflicts with the Accessory call I make above and might not work, but what I would do then (if you don't need `deviceMode`) then just check if the usb device is a HOST mode and if not you know it is in application mode...